# Logic app how to handle a null value in a compose action

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I got a scenario like below.

I make a call to a logic app with this example json. The projectDate object is optional. Sometimes its filled and when its not it is a null.

```
    {
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "ProjectId": "a7ba682e445494341e90636afc34e260",
      "ProjectDate": null
    }
  }
}
```

Now i have a compose action in which I compose a new dataset.

[Compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcTPh.png)

```
{
"ProjectDate": "",
"ProjectId": "a7ba682e445494341e90636afc34e260"
```

}

So it makes an empty string instead of the null value. How can i get this null value mapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [if expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#if) in the `Compose` action to judge whether the `ProjectDate` is null.

For example:

[image]

[image]

Expression:

```
if(equals(variables('ProjectDate'), ''),null,variables('ProjectDate'))
```

If the passed in `ProjectDate` is `null`, you should use this expression:

```
if(equals(variables('ProjectDate'), null),null,variables('ProjectDate'))
```

I did some tests and there seems to be no problem：

[image]

Note that you need to use `body('parse')?['data']?['object']?['ProjectDate']` instead of `variables('ProjectDate')`.

Comment: Thanks Frank, that did the job!